# Skimage : rotate image and fill the new formed background

Tags: python, scikit-image

When rotating an image using

```
import skimage

result = skimage.transform.rotate(img, angle=some_angle, resize=True)
# the result is the rotated image with black 'margins' that fill the blanks
```

The algorithm rotates the image but leaves the newly formed background black and there is no way - using the rotate function - to choose the color of the newly formed background.

Do you have any idea how to do choose the color of the background before rotating an image?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if your pic is a gray picture,use `cval` ;
if pic is rgb ,no good way,blow code works:

```
path3=r'C:\\Users\forfa\Downloads\1111.jpg'
img20=data.imread(path3)
import numpy as np
img3=transform.rotate(img20,45,resize=True,cval=0.1020544) #0.1020544 can be any unique float,the pixel outside your pic is [0.1020544]*3
c,r,k=img3.shape
for i in range(c):
    for j in range(r):
        if np.allclose(img3[i][j],[0.1020544]*3):
            img3[i][j]=[1,0,0]  #[1,0,0] is red pixel,replace pixel [0.1020544]*3  with red pixel [1,0,0]
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't guess that cval was for this purpose !

Answer (score 6):

Just use `cval` parameter

```
img3 = transform.rotate(img20, 45, resize=True, cval=1, mode ='constant')
img4 = img3 * 255
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a little annoying that the `cval` parameter to `skimage.transform.warp()` can only be a `scalar float`.

You can set it to any value outside of the range of your data (like -1), and use `np.where()` to fix it afterwards. Here's an example that sets the background of a 3-channel `image` to red:

```
output = tf.warp(image, tform, mode='constant', cval=-1,
                 preserve_range=True, output_shape=(256, 256), order=3)
w = np.where(output == -1)
output[w[0], w[1], :] = [255, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

tbh I don't know why everyone set the cval value to a strange value.
I think it's intuitive when you look at the documentation of the function

> **cval** : float, optional
> Used in conjunction with mode ‘constant’, the value outside the image boundaries.

Therefore depending on what your input image is, in my case, my picture already used `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`, therefore in order to set it to white, I can simply set `cval=255`.

If it's ndarray(img more than 1 channel), you can either rotate each channel separately, or set it to strange value then use `np.where` to replace afterward. (idk why but I just don't like this method lol)

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how do it, but maybe this help you

```
http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html
```

Good luck! ;)